# Uploading image and text values to server

Tags: ios, image, swift, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

I'm trying to create a new object with an image and some other values using multipart but I can't get it to work.

This is the code I was using without uploading an image (this works):

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: self.submitLink)!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let params = [
        "article": [
            "name" : name,
            "description" : fullDescription.text!,
            "subdescription" : sDescription,
            "category_id" : categoriesArray[self.categoryPicked]["id"] as! Int,
            "location_id" : locationsArray[self.locationPicked]["id"] as! Int,
            "Xcoordinate" : self.lat,
            "Ycoordinate" : self.lng,
            "user_id" : User.sharedInstance.userId,
            "article_images_attributes[][image]" : ""
        ]
    ]

    request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        print("article created.")
    })

    task.resume()
```

and this is the code I'm using at the moment (not working):

```
let params = [
        "article[name]" : name,
        "article[description]" : fullDescription.text!,
        "article[subdescription]" : sDescription,
        "article[category_id]" : categoriesArray[self.categoryPicked]["id"] as! Int,
        "article[location_id]" : locationsArray[self.locationPicked]["id"] as! Int,
        "article[Xcoordinate]" : self.lat,
        "article[Ycoordinate]" : self.lng,
        "article[user_id]" : User.sharedInstance.userId
    ]

    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"
    let fileParamConstant = "article[article_images_attributes][][image]"
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: self.submitLink)!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundaryConstant)"

    request.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let body = NSMutableData()
    for param in params {
        print(param)
        body.appendData("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; \(param.key)=\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("\(param.value)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoArray[0], 1)
    if imageData != nil {
        body.appendData("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\(fileParamConstant); filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData!)
        body.appendData("\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    body.appendData("--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    request.HTTPBody = body

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        print(request)
        print(data)
    })

    task.resume()
```

Whenever I try to submit my form the server replies with:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass)

So I assume there is something wrong with the way I defined my params? Could someone explain it to me a bit more in-depth so I know what I did wrong?

Comment: The server replies with said message? Have you used an http proxy, like Charles or Wireshark to investigate what's being sent?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong `Content-Type` for your image and the  `name` may not be correct.

Try something like this to set up your image:

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
double compressionRatio=0.7;
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((UIImage*)dataParam, compressionRatio);

[self utfAppendBody:body data:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\".jpg\"\r\n", paramName]];

[self utfAppendBody:body data:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"];
[body appendData:imageData];
```

With this helper function:

```
- (void)utfAppendBody:(NSMutableData *)body data:(NSString *)data {
    [body appendData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```